# Python - [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, macos, installation

I am trying to install a python script on my mac.
When I run $ `python setup.py install` I get the following message:

> running install
>   error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
>   installation directory:
>
> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-1668.write-test'
> ```
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
>   the distutils default setting) was:
>
> ```
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
> ```
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
>   installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
>   as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
>   access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
>   directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Tried `sudo python setup.py install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python setup.py install` may produce to `[Errno 13] Permission denied` error for writing in root folder.

You may try this

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

But **better** should be

- create virtual environment
- activate it

Then install by

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Inside a virtualenv didn't conflict to other system wide configs

Comment: "directory to install to that you have write permissions". So when user create a `virtualenv`, user will be the owner of it.So without root access can install.

Comment: I think `pip` will try defaultly to write package inside `/usr/` or some `root only write access folder`.So may get permission denied ? will it better to choose `virtualenv` than `sudo` ? I am not arguing you :)

Comment: K, then can install. but isn't it a good practice to use `virtualenv` ?